# extract text from the string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get text from the string
like i have a strings like this

- Converted Vice President Rank Award
- Converted Coordinator Rank Award

i want Vice **President** from this Converted Vice President Rank Award, 
**Coordinator** from this Converted Coordinator Rank Award

Converted and Rank always in the text so i need to extract text in the middle of it

Comment: This depends on the engine you are running your query

Comment: Please refer [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: HI @a_horse_with_no_name Updated

Comment: select trim(replace(replace('Converted Vice President Rank Award', 'Converted', ''),'Rank Award',''))

Comment: You can use `LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(<column name>,'Converted',''),'RANK AWARD','')))` as a temporary solution

Comment: Thanks @ankyskywalker

Answer (score 1):

Use this. Works with all `DBMS`.

**Oracle**

```
  With tab(col) as ( Select 'Converted Vice President Rank Award' from dual
                  UNION ALL
                  Select 'Converted Coordinator Rank Award' from dual
                  )
    --Query
    Select  replace(replace (col,'Converted',''),'Rank Award','')
    from tab;
```

**SQLSERVER**

```
With tab(col) as ( Select 'Converted Vice President Rank Award' 
              UNION ALL
              Select 'Converted Coordinator Rank Award' 
              )
--Query
Select  replace(replace (col,'Converted',''),'Rank Award','')
from tab;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e08dbfa2b3610e3077defe8fe20cc43)

Comment: Thanks @xing that what i am looking for and thanks every one helping a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

> To get "Vice President" from this Converted Vice President Rank Award,
>    "Coordinator" from this Converted Coordinator Rank Award.

**Syntax**:-
SUBSTRING(string, start, length)

> You can try this this SQL Server Query:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Converted Vice President Rank Award', 11, 14) AS String,SUBSTRING('Converted Coordinator Rank Award', 11, 11) AS String1;
```

**Note**:-In the place of string you can write column name in which your string exist.

Comment: Hi @aditya its sort of hard code i have different string as well with same format

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring for such situations where you have already given a string:

**Syntax** : `substring(word,start,end)`

```sql
SELECT substring('Vice President Rank AwardVice President Rank Award',6,10),
       substring('Coordinator Rank Award',1,11)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi @Nikita Shisodia its sort of hard code i have different string as well with same format

Comment: hello @dev88 for fetching data from string you can use substring as well as regular expression